# Devise Registration form is still creating a user despite Stripe not being valid RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, stripe-payments

I am using Devise to manage Users and am using Stripe to set up 3 seperate subscription plans. However, when the Stripe fields are empty or invalid, it will flash an error screen and still create a new User except without a Plan ID

```
No such token: undefined
```

The registration controller looks like this.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :select_plan, only: :new

  def create
    super do |resource|
      if params[:plan]
        resource.plan_id = params[:plan]
        if resource.plan_id == 4 || resource.plan_id == 5 || resource.plan_id == 6
          resource.save_with_payment
        else
          resource.save
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def select_plan
      unless params[:plan] && (params[:plan] == '4' || params[:plan] == '5' || params[:plan] == '6')
      flash[:notice] = "Please select a membership plan to sign up."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
    end
end
```

The following is the model I am using for my User.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :plan
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    else
      redirect_to root_url
      flash[:Danger] = "There was an error with processing your payment. Please try again."
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are inconsistency in multiple places.

You're enforcing `select_plan` before filter on `new` action, not in `create` action!

```
before_filter :select_plan, only: :new
```

You're saving the record either way, even if it doesn't have a plan:

```
if resource.plan_id == 4 || resource.plan_id == 5 || resource.plan_id == 6
  resource.save_with_payment
else
  resource.save
end
```

And finally you're calling `redirect_to` method from inside model. These calls must be in controller, not in model.

```
redirect_to root_url
flash[:Danger] = "There was an error with processing your payment. Please try again."
```

Comment: I've changed all these inconsistencies and am still getting the problem. The problem is, it will go through to resource.save_with_payment even though stripe fields are incorrect and then it is unable to generate a stripe token hence giving me an error message.

However, even after all this, it still saves my user.